Dynamic File Access(python310.dll) Challenge in Executable Python Script
The environment on my work computer imposes strict limitations, prompting me to compile a Python script into an executable using Pyinstaller. This circumvents the need for administrators to install Python and its associated modules, which would be a more complex process.
However, one of the essential files required by the .exe, "python310.dll," encounters consistent blocking. Although the administrators have granted access to it, the file's location changes with each execution (typically to "AppData/Local/Temp/23/" followed by a dynamically generated folder). Despite unblocking it, a new blocked version appears upon running the executable, rendering the script inoperable.
I suggested whitelisting either the filename or its parent folder, but the administrators dismissed this due to perceived security risks.
Is there a viable solution to this dilemma? Perhaps a method to ensure the required files remain static during script execution? Alternatively, are there alternative compilation methods besides Pyinstaller that might mitigate this issue?
Thank you in advance for any assistance or insights you can provide!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
